# How to return the version (changeset) of a file in a workspace using the TFS object model?

Tags: tfs

How can the version (changeset) of a file in a workspace be returned using the TFS object model?  I want to be able to pass in the path of a file in my workspace and have the changeset returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general approach:

```
var versionControl = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var item =
    versionControl.GetItem(
        "$/TeamProject/Main/Solution/Program.cs",
        new WorkspaceVersionSpec("workspace", "user"));

int changesetId = item.ChangesetId;
```

The key is the WorkspaceVersionSpec object.